# How to create a prefab and specify the fall rate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

Is there a way to make it fall by changing the y value of Vector3 in this code?

I want to create an object with y coordinate 7 and x coordinate randomly and fall, but I want to specify the fall speed
When using rigid2D, it falls, but it only falls at a constant speed, so I want to use a variable rather than a constant speed to drop the speed.

````
        this.delta += Time.deltaTime;
        if (this.delta > this.span)
        {
            //arrowController.speed = -0.000f;
            this.delta = 0;
            GameObject go = Instantiate(arrowPrefeb) as GameObject;
            int px = Random.Range(-9, 9);
            go.transform.position = new Vector3(px,7,0);
            
            if (span >= 0.1f)
            {
                this.span *= 0.9f;
                this.round.GetComponent<Text>().text = "점점 빨라지는 중!";
            }
            else
            {
                span = 0.09f;
                this.round.GetComponent<Text>().text = "피해 보아요!";
            }
        }
        
    }```
````

Comment: Is `0.9f` your "fall rate", and you want to introduce a variable for this?

Comment: What about using unity built in gravity. Set it on your prefab's rigidbody2D inspector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can introduce a field

```
public float FallSpeed = 0;
```

(you will be able to change this value in the inspector before you start the game)

then in the update loop of the same script....

```
void Update() 
{ 
    this.transform.position += new Vector3(0f, FallSpeed, 0f); 
}
```